# Justifying non-expert lecturer

Tags: undergraduate-education

If a maths lecturer is lecturing a higher-level undergraduate course outside their area (i.e. has not taken a course in themselves or learned themselves over the course of their research), how could you justify to the students that they are suitably qualified to teach and assess them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you should be justifying the lecturer's qualifications to the students. Presumably your department has ascertained that the individual is indeed knowledgeable enough in the area to provide high-level instruction (that is very important). That should be suitable justification in and of itself. To maintain that trust, it is essential to never permit an unqualified individual to instruct a course.

Comment: I'd go with "you cannot".

Comment: It depends on the background of the Lecturer. After some point of mathematical maturity it becomes comparatively simple to assimilate new material. Also, if this person is a good teacher and cares about the students then they'll take the time to see how other folks are teaching similar courses at other good institutions. But, the students, well, as long as he doesn't grade too hard they'll be fine.

Comment: I agree you don't justify it.  More to the point, a person's qualifications only guarantee their expertise in an area and do not necessarily reflect their capacity as teachers.

Comment: Could you contextualize this question a bit more? Right now, you could cross out the word *maths* from the question and it'd read essentially the same; is there some way in which this being *math*-specific should/would/could affect the answer? Also confusing: Is the person a *non-expert* (as in the title) or generally unfamiliar with the material (as in the body)? There's a difference between a non-expert and a total naif. Finally: *Is* the person "suitably qualified" for this position? If yes: Why? If no: This question looks to me like it is asking about tricking students.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Where this question actually comes from is that I'm having a discussion with colleagues from other subjects that basically comes down to the question of what makes you suitably qualified to teach at this level. I think being in maths rather than another subject could affect the answer. I also want to discount the argument 'we haven't got anyone suitable so they will have to do', which I suspect students would complain about if they found out.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Also, I don't understand your distinction between the title and the body, as they are intended to be the same. I mean someone who is generally sufficiently qualified that they have been hired by the university, but teaching a course far enough from their specialty that is not immediately obvious that they are a suitable choice.

Comment: "I think being in maths rather than another subject could affect the answer." - Based on my discussions with colleagues in other disciplines, I do think it is somewhat peculiar to mathematics that people often are called upon to teach completely out of their 'specialty' (and not just generalist courses).  Plenty of math PhDs with no statistics background whatsoever are asked to teach both intro and mathematical statistics every year!

Comment: @kcrisman Actually, I would have gone the other way round. I've been talking to people who teach in a completely different subject. But it seems to me that 'statistics' or 'research methods' might translate better between subjects than does in maths, where the content is the maths.

Comment: Interesting, that would be the opposite of my experience, where e.g. a historian might feel very uncomfortable teaching Modern Asian History if their dissertation was in Medieval European or something, whereas an analyst could be perfectly well expected to teach upper-level number theory or probability in a small department or if someone was on sabbatical, even if they'd never had the course.

Comment: It may depend on the type of institution, of course; at a Research I might be very different than at tiny liberal arts college X or comprehensive regional state University Y.

Comment: Huston's [Teaching What You Don't Know](http://www.amazon.com/Teaching-What-You-Dont-Know/dp/0674066170) might be worth picking up.

Comment: @kcrisman, who says the mathematician isn't equally conflicted?

Comment: @vonbrand I'm not sure which of my comments you're specifically referring to, but I only put my thoughts there as a comment because they are anecdotal in any case; my answer below is (I hope) orthogonal to it.  I am sure that in many cases the math instructor may feel pretty unqualified, that is true, and assuredly many of them won't feel it is fair or a good idea.  My point was just that it seems like this might be a more common thing in mathematics teaching than in other disciplines - but no, I don't have comprehensive data either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comments are very interesting, but you are talking about how to justify to students.  That may not always be necessary, but here is a stab at it if someone really asked (which I find somewhat unlikely).

> The instructor has a PhD in mathematics, which means that s/he has learned not just how to learn independently, but how to become an expert in mathematical subject matter.  Given the interconnectedness of mathematics, I am confident that Dr. X will do an excellent job not only with the subject at hand, but how it fits into your studies in general, both before and after this class.

Some may disagree with this characterization, but anyway I think it's more true than not.

Obviously the first time won't be the best, but that is something that can be said for any course when taught the first time, including freshman calculus/college algebra/finite mathematics or whatever your "first" college course happens to be.  How many people really "get" the Mean Value Theorem until they have to teach it?  Proving random stuff with it in some undergraduate real analysis course also likely lies years behind instructor Y or Z, not just instructor X.

Comment: (Something you might *not* want to say is that the instructor might actually be more motivated - and hence better - by getting to learn something they didn't learn before but always wanted to, as opposed to something they now find sort of uninspiring or boring.  It's likely to be true reasonably often, but probably students won't like that rationale as much.)

Comment: Not only a non-specialist can be more motivated, but he or she can see more easily what is difficult to understand, not having years of habits to hide difficulties from her or him.

Answer (score 9):

Usually undergraduate level courses are not very difficult for experienced researchers/lecturers. Even without previous research experience in the specific topic, lecturers can learn the material very fast and be able to teach the topic to students well enough afterwards.

However, it may be the case that the lecturer *appears* to be unqualified or unfit to teach the material, but based on my personal experience I think this often reflects on the lecturer's ability to *teach* rather than their knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 8):

In France, my answer would be that **we only hire faculty who can teach every mathematical subject at every undergraduate level** (possibly with quite some work, of course). This is most usually included in the job description, and is pretty accurate in practice.

One thing that makes it relatively easy to ensure that a good majority of faculty have this broadness is that a good majority of us have taken *Agrégation*, a national competition intended to hire high school teachers of higher mathematical level, where one has to demonstrate a good mastery of a big chunk of undergraduate mathematics.

Another point is that the higher education in *Écoles Normales Supérieures* is very broad: one does not specialize too much too early; and a good majority of faculty in France went to one of these *ENS*. Of course, we also hire people whose higher education was at a university, and foreign mathematicians, but many of them are equally broad, and all in all I think the vast majority of faculty is able to teach any undergraduate course, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The one thing I would add--hopefully not considered a segue--is to avoid justifying or opening up a discussion of justifying.  The natural impetus of the students is to assume competence of the instructor.  Don't weaken that.

You may feel an urge to confession ("first time teaching this" or "never took this"), but it is likely you are trying to gain sympathy or to set expectations lower.  This is a natural human thing to do, especially for bright people with inverse Dunning-Kreuger.  But don't do it.  Stay positive, stay in control, and just do your best to teach a great course...with a stiff upper lip about your lack of experience.  Nobody wants to hear your issues...they want to learn the topic.

Source: instructor training for first aid and skiing.  Absolutely do not tell your classes, you are a first timer.  And I believe the commonality here is psychology and pedagogy.  Not course content.  IOW, the "educators" part is dominant, not the "mathematics" part.

Comment: I have come across situations where the students do not automatically accept the lecturer. Besides, I don't think it's really appropriate to be doing something like that if it can't be justified to the students.

Answer (score 2):

Assessment is the easy part, anyone who is well versed in the logic of mathematics should be able to vet the student's proofs and computations.

Teaching is less clear. You want the lecturer to know what the important parts are. If they aren't familiar with the subject, how are they going to know where the most fertile ideas can be found? (This can be remedied if there is a good textbook available.) Still, you can always run the class --- not as a lecture --- but as a seminar where everyone is upfront about the fact that everyone, including the professor, is learning the subject together. I've certainly had classes like that in graduate school, for emerging topics. They were fun!

Comment: I think there are problems with assessment. While in theory you should be able to verify correctness, I find that even in familiar topics it can be hard to spot all the tricks that sound reasonably but are not right for some fairly subtle reason. Judging the value of an incorrect answer seems potentially problematic too. Everyone learning together sounds fine for graduate level, but I find it hard to picture that working so well in an undergraduate context where a mark has to given at the end.